Scaling single Azure Container App worker using MassTransit and Azure ServiceBus
I am using MassTransit and have a worker deployed to an Azure Container App. In an attempt to keeps costs as low as possible, I would like the container to scale to zero.
Given that I use the default mechanisms built into MassTransit to create the topology I am seeking guidance on a few things.

Since I am not really aware of the names of the entities in ServiceBus until they are created at runtime, what is the process / guidance / best practices for programmatically creating scale rules in the container app so that it can scale to zero but also spin the container up when work needs to be done?
How are scaling rules built in container apps for topics? The only available rules I see are for queues?
I am using bicep to deploy resources to my azure subscription. Is there some method available for me to know what the names of the entities will be ahead of time so that I can create the scaling rules during this step?


There is a video series on container apps, where I go over KEDA scaling rules with ASB queues. Might be some help.

I think part of what I was missing here was the Service Bus Auto-Forwarding that was happening when a message was published and how the consumer would read that message from the queue and not from topic subscription. This is mentioned in the documentation but not in the video series.
What I still do not have a grasp on is how I can know all the names of the queues ahead of time so that I can properly configure the container app with a scaling rule for the exhaustive list of queues. This would allow me to scale to zero when no work was present but spin up the container when work was ready.
